# Deploying Android app to testers

Tags: android, android-studio, testing

Is there some way to deploy Android app to your beta testers directly from Android Studio?
It can be some way(plugin for Android Studio) to load app to Google Play Store as alpha test apk or so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't any way like xcode of iOS! but there are many ways to test them and one of the convenient way would be using: [TestFairy](https://testfairy.com/)